# Android Rss feed inside a widget

Tags: android, android-widget, rss-reader

I try to write a **widget** that getting placed on the home screen with this code:

```
package com.example.anirudh.chatter;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


    void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv1, "hello");
        System.out.print("abcdef");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        intent.setAction("update");

        //This pending intent will run the intent created above
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnRefresh, pi);

        new MyAsyncTask().execute(context);


        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equals("update")) {
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(context);
            System.out.print("abcdef");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
        Context context;
        RemoteViews views;


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Context... params) {
            context = params[0];
            ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.codingconnect.net/feed");
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = true;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline

                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                        }
                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = false;
                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print("heads:" + headlines);
            return headlines;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> heads) {
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv1, " ");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv2, " ");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv3, " ");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv4, " ");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv5, " ");
            if (heads != null && heads.size() >= 5) {
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv1, heads.get(0));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv2, heads.get(1));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv3, heads.get(2));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv4, heads.get(3));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv5, heads.get(4));
            }
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
            try {
                return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the widget has no data when displayed on the text views.

The `onRecieve` method is never called and so is the **Asynctask** which is used for rss-feed headings which have to be placed in the text views.

Anybody know whats wrong in my code?